# Как адекватно связать поля в модели данных с помощью SQLAlchemy?

Tags: sqlite, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, wtforms

Исходные:
приложение на flask
инфраструктура бд - flask-sqlAlchemy + sqlite
особенности - прикладное ненагруженное приложение со сложной системой моделей данных, которые параллельно связаны и влияют друг на друга, выстраивая динамическую иерархическую систему, существующую параллельно в нескольких иерархических состояниях. Были выбраны реляционные БД.

```
class Attribute(db.Model):
  id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
  attributename= db.Column(db.String(120), index=True, unique=False)
  source= db.Column(db.String(120), index=True, unique=False)
  description = db.Column(db.Text, index=True)

class Criteria(db.Model):
  id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
  criteria= db.Column(db.String(64), index=True, unique=True)

class Classification(db.Model):
  id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
  source= db.Column(db.String(120), index=True, unique=False)
  description = db.Column(db.Text, index=True)

class Node(db.Model):
  id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
  parent_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('node.id'))
  attribute_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('attribute.id'))
  criteria_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('criteria.id'))
  classification_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('classification.id'))
  left = db.Column("lft", db.Integer, index=True, nullable=False)
  right = db.Column("rgt", db.Integer, index=True, nullable=False)

  childs = db.relationship('Node', backref=db.backref("parent", remote_side=id),lazy="dynamic")
  attribute= db.relationship('Attribute', backref='node')
  criteria= db.relationship('Criteria', backref='node')
  classification = db.relationship('Classification', backref='node')
```

Модель, с которой будет происходить большинство операций - Node. она выполняет и роль связывающей таблицы, и несет в себе информацию об иерархии. На базовом этапе я хочу, чтобы работала она. А потом я добавлю нужные параметры, чтобы использовать ее для организации и отображения других моделей. В данной редакции схема прошла проверку при инициализации и миграции баз данных, при создании всех сущностей, кроме Node. А вот попытка использовать модель Node ведет к ошибке бд (sqlite3.InterfaceError). Так как не выходит с одним связанным параметром, то остальные я не прописывал.

Как я использую эту модель (flask-wtforms):

```
class NodeForm(FlaskForm):
  criteria_id = SelectField(u'Criteria', coerce=int)
  submit = SubmitField('Add new')

@app.route('/add-node', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def addnode():
  criteria = Criteria.query.get(id)
  form = NodeForm(request.POST, obj=criteria)
  form.criteria_id.choices = [(g.id, g.criteria) for g in Criteria.query]
  form = NodeForm()
  if form.validate_on_submit():
    criteria= Node(criteria_id=form.criteria_id.data)
    db.session.add(criteria)
    db.session.commit()
    flash('New Node created!')
    return redirect(url_for('addnode'))
  return render_template('addnode.html', form=form)
```

Что нужно в этой форме: на страничке добавления новой сущности Node вывести список уже готовых связанных сущностей Criteria, из которого выбрать одну, идентификатор которой запишется в соответствующее поле (criteria_id в модели Node).

Это элементарные вещи, я многократно сверялся с мануалами и документацией, но не смог решить проблему, как описать связи в модели так, чтобы их можно было использовать.

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял вопрос (мне было сложно понять из описания), но мне кажется проблема ваша решается добавлением промежуточной таблицы в которой будут хранится связанные Criteria с вашим Node, например вот так:

```
class Criteria(db.Model):

    __tablename__ = 'criterias'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    criteria= db.Column(db.String(64), index=True, unique=True)

# Эта таблица не объявлена в качестве модели SQLAlchemy, так как это вспомогательная
# таблица со связью Many-To-Many, которая не имеет данных, кроме ForeignKey ключей.
nodes_criterias = db.Table('nodes_criterias',
    db.Column('node_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('nodes.id', ondelete='CASCADE'), nullable=False),
    db.Column('criteria_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('criterias.id', ondelete='CASCADE'), nullable=False)
)

class Node(db.Model):

    __tablename__ = 'nodes'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    parent_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('node.id'))
    attribute_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('attribute.id'))
    criteria_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('criteria.id'))
    classification_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('classification.id'))
    left = db.Column("lft", db.Integer, index=True, nullable=False)
    right = db.Column("rgt", db.Integer, index=True, nullable=False)

    childs = db.relationship('Node', backref=db.backref("parent", remote_side=id),lazy="dynamic")
    attribute = db.relationship('Attribute', backref='node')
    classification = db.relationship('Classification', backref='node')

    # Many-To-Many
    criterias = db.relationship(
        'Criteria',
        secondary=nodes_criterias, # Промежуточная таблица
        primaryjoin=(nodes_criterias.c.node_id == id),
        secondaryjoin=(nodes_criterias.c.criteria_id == Criteria.id),
        backref=db.backref('node', lazy='dynamic'),
        # order_by=Criteria.id.desc(),
        lazy='dynamic'
    )

    # Добавление criteria к node
    def add_criteria(criteria):
        self.criterias.append(criteria)

    # Так как self.criterias это список, то доступны все методы списка:
    def remove_criteria(criteria):
        self.criterias.remove(criteria)
```

Далее в коде вы можете использовать:

```
# Добавить к конкретному Node свою criteria
for n in Node.query.all():
    n.add_criteria(criteria)

# Вывести все связанные criteria с Node:
node = Node.query.filter(...).first()
node.criterias.all() # Выведет все criteria связанные с Node
```